# What features are supported by CouchDB javascript engine

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I want to make a `validate_doc_update`. What features are supported for this function by CouchDB? Can I use `Array.find`, `Array.map`, `Object.keys` and other functions like those? If latest version supports those features, which CouchDB version should I target to make sure my validation will work seamlessly on every system - I would retrieve CouchDB version and make it's above said version.

Comment: CouchDB uses SpiderMonkey by default. Which version (and there fore which JS features are supported) probably depends on your version of CouchDB. Which version of CouchDB are you using?

Comment: I'm using v2.0.0. Anyway I found that Array.filter works while Array.find doesn't